# MPDF different file sizes per operating system

Tags: php, linux, macos, ghostscript, mpdf

I am using mPDF and Ghostscript as a part of a larger application, where the is workflow is as this:

1. A PDF is uploaded by a 3rd party software
2. The file is detected and converted to PDF 1.4 (via a GhostScript wrapper: https://github.com/xthiago/pdf-version-converter)
3. Based on the converted file a new PDF file is generated

In local env (MacOS), because the files uploaded are version 1.6, the converted file has more or less half the size of the original and the same goes for the new created one, but in production server (Ubuntu), even if the converted one has the same size as its local equivalent, the new one has 10x times more size: (eg 48MB vs 480MB)

What might be the case for such difference?

The code used is as this:

```
$mPdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(array(
'dpi' => 300
));

$mPdf -> SetImportUse();
$pageCount = $mPdf -> SetSourceFile($productFileToCopy);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
   $importPage = $mPdf -> ImportPage($i);
   $wh = $mPdf -> getTemplateSize($importPage);
   $orientation = $wh['w'] > $wh['h'] ? 'L' : 'P';
   $mPdf -> AddPageByArray(array(
     'orientation' => $orientation,
     'sheet-size' => array(
       $orientation === 'L' ? $wh['h'] : $wh['w'],
       $orientation === 'L' ? $wh['w'] : $wh['h'],
      ),
      'margin-left' => 0,
      'margin-right' => 0,
      'margin-top' => 0,
      'margin-bottom' => 0,
      'margin-header' => 0,
      'margin-footer' => 0,
    ));

    $mPdf -> UseTemplate($importPage);
 }

 $mPdf -> Output($productFileFinal);
```

Comment: @jww thanks for the clarification, but since I believe that the problem lies in the mPDF PHP library and how it needs to be configured as per operating system, then this might be the place for the question.

Comment: @jww you are right, I'll edit my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's not mPDF, but Ghostscript.

Slightly different version (9.22 vs 9.23) produces 10x bigger files under this command

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -dColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged -dEncodeColorImages=false -dEncodeGrayImages=false -dEncodeMonoImages=false -dDownsampleMonoImages=false -dDownsampleGrayImages=false -dDownsampleColorImages=false -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode
```

Comment: Are you saying that 9.22 is larger or smaller ? I doubt anyone can help without seeing the original file.

Comment: @KenS version 9.22 produces 10x bigger files no matter the original file

Comment: Well in that case, use 9.23 :-) I still can't really comment without seeing the original file, there's no possible way to tell what might cause the older version to produce larger files.